# Sprite not showing up on pygame window

Tags: python, pygame

I just started using pygame and I'm confused about why my sprite isn't showing up in the window...

Here's my main code for the game:

```py
import pygame

from Classes.Car import Car

pygame.init()
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREY = (167, 167, 167)

size = (700, 500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("My First Game")

all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
playerCar = Car(BLACK, 20, 30)

playerCar.rect.x = 200
playerCar.rect.y = 300
all_sprites_list.add(playerCar)

carryOn = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while carryOn:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            carryOn = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_x:
                carryOn = False
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        playerCar.moveLeft(5)
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        playerCar.moveRight(5)
    all_sprites_list.update()
    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)
    screen.fill(GREEN)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREY, [150, 0, 400, 500], 0)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, WHITE, [150, 0], [150, 500], 3)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, WHITE, [250, 0], [250, 500], 3)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, WHITE, [350, 0], [350, 500], 3)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, WHITE, [450, 0], [450, 500], 3)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, WHITE, [550, 0], [550, 500], 3)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
pygame.quit()
```

And here's my class, which was made in a different file called Car.py:

```py
import pygame
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
GREY = (167, 167, 167)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)


class Car(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, color, width, height):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(WHITE)
        self.image.set_colorkey(GREY)
        pygame.draw.rect(self.image, color, [0, 0, width, height])
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def moveRight(self, pixels):
        self.rect.x += pixels

    def moveLeft(self, pixels):
        self.rect.x -= pixels
```

Please give me any pointers on how I can clarify my question a little more. This is my first time really asking anything here.

Comment: It looks like you fill the screen with green after you draw your sprite

Comment: Thank you, I just realized that I drew my sprite under the whole background... I don't know how I didn't catch that earlier.

Comment: Sometimes you just need a fresh set of eyes :-)

Answer (score 1):

The car doesn't show up because it is covered. `screen.fill(GREEN)` does not just set a color, it fills the entire screen with the `GREEN` color.
Fill the screen first. Then draw the gray street and finally draw the sprites on top. Update the display at the end:

```py
while carryOn:

    # [...]

    screen.fill(GREEN)

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREY, [150, 0, 400, 500], 0)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, WHITE, [150, 0], [150, 500], 3)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, WHITE, [250, 0], [250, 500], 3)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, WHITE, [350, 0], [350, 500], 3)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, WHITE, [450, 0], [450, 500], 3)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, WHITE, [550, 0], [550, 500], 3)

    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.flip()
```